# R: On scoping, passing arguments to interior functions, and

Tags: r, scope, parameter-passing

The example below is another instance of my ongoing quest to be better at predicting what R will do. Despite having read the material on matching and scoping any number of times, I continue to have difficulty in passing variables, and it seems clear that there are either additional rules I am missing, or I am misunderstanding some of the rules I have, supposedly, learned.

Here `ff()` calls `gg()` four times. The output of these calls is below. Here instance 1 and 2 confirm my expectations. They find `aa` in the execution environment of `ff`, and `cc` in the enclosing environment of the function definition of `gg`. But instances 2 and 3 surprised me. For 3, I was not sure what would happen, as I am still a little foggy on whether a variable passed via `...` retains its name.  If not, I figured the garbage collector might get it. But I really expected 4 to pass a variable called `cc` with the value 13 into the function, and it does not.

My original version of `gg()` did not have the `ls()` the `list2env()` in it. When I added the `ls()`, it seemed to show that the `...` passed a `...` object, with the `cc` inaccessible inside it to the scope of the cc in the function body. Note that the ls() did not show the `...` until I added the all.names=TRUE. I then added the list2env(), conditional on there being something in the`...`. but as best I can tell, this does nothing at all.

So, three questions:

1. What is up with list2env? Why does it have no effect here?
2. How does one make named arguments (in the sense of an argument
   assigned a name by tag) in a `...` generally available inside the
   function as if the name had been a formal?
3. Same question as (2), but with respect to a variable that has a
   name, or is a name, without that name being assigned via tag in the
   argument list.

```
aa <- 2
bb <- 3
cc <- 11
gg <- function(X, ...){
  if(length(alist(...)) > 1){list2env(alist(...), envir = parent.frame())} 
  env_vars <- ls(all.names=TRUE)
  out <-  cc * X
  print(env_vars)
  cat(X, ",  out = ", out, "\n", sep="")
}

ff <- function(){
  aa <- 5
  bb <- 7
  cc <- 13

  gg(aa)        \# 1
  gg(X=aa)      \# 2
  gg(aa, cc)    \# 3
  gg(aa, cc=cc) \# 4
}

ff()

[1] "..." "X"  
5,  out = 55
[1] "..." "X"  
5,  out = 55
[1] "..." "X"  
5,  out = 55
[1] "..." "X"  
5,  out = 55
```

A big thank you! to whoever fixed my formatting.

Comment: [Here's a hint on formatting code after an ordered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34292/code-blocks-after-a-list-but-not-within-a-list-in-markdown-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does seem strange but with some trial and error we find that

```
L <- list(...)
list2env(L, environment())
```

will inject the `...` variables into the current environment if the actual arguments are named.  It seems that it is important to create an intermediate variable to hold the list, here `L`.

In general one could use `with` like this if the actual arguments are named:

```
g <- function(X, ...) with(list(...), {
   print(ls())
})
g(1, cc = 2)
## [1] "cc"
```

Comment: It seems you were answering my question while I was editing it. You are fast! But perhaps you could look at the new question number 3?

Comment: An actual argument could be an expression so you can't assume that every actual argument has a name.  As a commenter pointed out `match.call()` can be used to return a language object representing the call and the expressions used as its actual arguments.

Comment: I do not really expect to pass nameless arguments through ..., as it would seem to be dificult, once inside the body, to tell them where to go. You would have to match them positionall, which sort of defeats the purpose -- if you know the order, why not just add formals. But I would like to know how to use ... to pass into the body arguments of the form xx,  xx=2, or xx=<expression>.

Comment: I just tried your "with" construction with all three of the argument types from my last comment. Based on an ls(), it worked for an xx=2 argument and an xx=<expression> argument, but not for a plain xx argument. But I am not sure that is a fair test and will experiment further.

Comment: I an attempt to get with(..., <expr>) to work with vars that have names but aren't "named", i.e. tagged, I tried  providing <...> with xx = get("xx", envir=parent.frame()). I wanted to use the xx in the calling env., rather than the enclosing env. of the function definition - like a name as actual arg. It does not work for that purpose; xx in the body finds the xx in the function's enclosing env. rather than its calling env. -- not sure why. I keep wanting to find similar or parallel ways of dealing with named (i.e. tagged) variables & variables with names.  Maybe I just need to get over it.

Comment: You can use `h <- function() eval.parent(substitute({ ls() })); h()` which will run everything within the brace brackets (in this example, just `ls()` ) in the parent and have access to all its variables.